# Q-Chainage plugin. Chain points layer does not save properly

Tags: vector, qchainage

Using Windows 10, QGIS latest version.
Use Q chainage (vector plugin) to make a chain of points on a boundary (line vector layer).
I save the points layer (as layer definition file), and also save the whole project.
When I close and then return to the Project, the points are not there. 
The name of the layer is listed in the layers, but it is empty.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the layer as a shapefile or similar. A layer definition file saves only the style in case you want to apply it to another layer later

[image]